# How to display custom validation error in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have built a lightning lightning component.I am invoking the custom lightning component using quick Action.

I have used lighning:input tags.

I have to perform client side validation on click of a button and show the error message to the user.

What is the best way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the custom validation error in the lightning:input component. In below example, If you write **John Doe** in input field and press register, you will get an error message.

```
    <aura:component>
        <lightning:input aura:id="inputCmp" label="Enter your name:" name="fullName" />
        <lightning:button label="Register" onclick="{! c.register }" />
    </aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
    ({
    register : function(component, event) {
        var inputCmp = component.find("inputCmp");
        var value = inputCmp.get("v.value");
        // is input valid text?
        if (value === "John Doe") {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity("John Doe is already registered");
        } else {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity(""); // if there was a custom error before, reset it
        }
        inputCmp.reportValidity(); // Tells lightning:input to show the error right away without needing interaction
    }
})
```

Read more here:- [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation)

Comment: I am using Aura components not LWC. Also, submit button is at the end of the page where as lightning:input is at the beginning. User might have to scroll up to view the error message as there are multiple lightning:input fields. Is there any other way to display the error message at the button itself?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. But the challenge still remains the same. My lightning component is too big and it contains multiple fields. Field on which the error has occurred is not available in the screen when the user performs submit button click. User has to scroll up to see the error message. User might get confused why page is not getting submitted on click of submit button if he does not scroll up. Can we display an error icon on button?